# How to use subtraction function in Soapui test request

Tags: soapui

I want to use subtraction function in my test step.
Below is the code where I want to use subtraction

```
<Payment>
      <Paymentmethod PartialAmount="${TestStep1#Response#//Node1/Price}">
</Payment>
```

In above code i want to subtract a value from Property. For example property value code is ${TC-property#cash}

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a simple Groovy one-line script:

```
<Payment>
      <Paymentmethod PartialAmount="${= Double.parseDouble('${TC-property#cash}') - 10.0 }">
</Payment>
```